# Minimal PySpark in AWS EMR fails to create a spark context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying use PySpark in a fresh AWS EMR Spark cluster, and it is failing with the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 20 more
```

What I am doing:

1. On EMR console, create a new cluster (`emr-5.12.1` with Spark, `m4.large`, 2 instances)
2. SSH its master
3. create a new `virtualenv` with Python 3, install `pyspark`, and create a context:

   ```
   export PROJECT=example
   python3 -m venv ~/.virtualenvs/$PROJECT
   source ~/.virtualenvs/$PROJECT/bin/activate
   pip install pyspark
   export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/hadoop/.virtualenvs/$PROJECT/bin/python
   export YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
   python -c "import pyspark; conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster('yarn-client').setAppName('testing'); sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)"
   ```

which raises the exception above.

What I also tried:

1. use Python 2 instead (`virtualenv ~/.virtualenvs/$PROJECT`)
2. use the default Python installation, not creating any virtualenv.

The exception is closely related to [this issue in Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15343), but that was being caused by a old Hadoop version (2.6, 2.7), which is not the case in the configuration `emr-5.12.1`, that uses Hadoop 2.8.

I reproduced the same setup in Google Platform, and it works.

Note that if I call `pyspark` from the shell, it will work. However, the master will be set `local`:

```
 pyspark
 >>> sc
 <SparkContext master=local[*] appName=PySparkShell>
```

which is useless for distributed jobs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to also export `SPARK_HOME`. I.e. on the step 3, use

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/hadoop/.virtualenvs/$PROJECT/bin/python
export YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
python -c "import pyspark; conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster('yarn-client').setAppName('testing'); sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)"
```

This addresses the problem in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with HDP, added SPARK_HOME as environment variable:

```
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = '/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client'
```

or

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client
```